# How large a snake can a Yuan-Ti Abomination become?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, polymorph, creature-size

In the Monster Manual (p. 308) it states:

> The yuan-ti can use its action to polymorph into a Large snake...

Can the snake be as large as I want or is there a set size?  The description wasn't specific.

Answer (score 36):

In this context "Large" means of the Large size category (Player's Handbook p.191), meaning it occupies a 10' by 10' space. The exact phrase is the following:

> The yuan-ti can use its action to polymorph into a Large snake, or back into its true form.

Note that the capital-L Large refers to a size category, not a general indication of bigness.

Comment: You may want to alter "occupy" to "control". The size categories aren't really about actual size, but more about the area that is controlled by a creature (but they do give some guidance in sizing because of that.)

Comment: The rules also use "takes up" as well as "controls". "Occupies" probably works well enough for general usage.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the tile space that Large creatures take up according to the *Dungeon Master's Guide,* I'd guess that a Large snake would be somewhere around 10-20 feet. Of course, you could customize it so your snake is larger or smaller, though you might have to change the size to Medium or Huge, and possibly adjust some damage or challenge ratings around.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: It should be noted that the game statistic "size" does not necessarily correlate with the physical dimensions of the creature's form, rather, it is the amount of space the creature controls in combat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).